# Is there a way to make R code only able to be run and not edited? Essentially read-only?

Tags: r, security, permissions, rstudio

I am in the midst of writing some scripts to perform data analysis on large excel sheets faster than by hand. However, my company has a strict quality review system where the program used needs to be validated and secure (i.e. no one can edit it, there is proof of what code was run, etc.). So essentially I would like my code to be able to be ran by my coworkers without them being able to edit the script. I was also interested in inserting prompts that they can fill in (e.g. "Which column would you like to analyze?")

Is all of this possible? I have read a few things online about file permissions but I know that these can easily be changed by the user. I also read about obfuscators but am entirely unfamiliar with their use.

One thought I have is to use Rmarkdown as a method of displaying which lines were run for which results. However, I believe that document could be edited as well? This would also leave the issue of the script itself being able to be edited.

Comment: If your colleagues have to fill in the variables of interest you will have some kind of change to your analyses. So complete read only does not seem feasible to me. Did you look into shiny apps? Than your code is in the app, from which the colleagues can retrieve the results with their input.

Comment: Perhaps, you can create a package for this. I have done this this to encapsulate data base access. Code is read only there. I believe you can also add Rmarkdown files with parameters. Another alternative would be a Shiny app.

Comment: A common solution to this problem is to put the script on a production linux server and set the file permissions to read-only for all users but a specific linux group.

Comment: I guess that would require users who know how to access on a linux server. Another option is to put it in a git repo hosted online e.g. GitHub. Then people can download the file and run it but can't change the "official" script on GitHub. They could of course download the script and change it before running, but this approach would at least allow you to maintain an official copy and cover your own back wrt others changing the script.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the very speedy answers! I am going to give RShiny a shot (through shinyapps.io) and see if it can attain the functionality that I need. I appreciate all of the feedback!